# Create Protected Metadata During Unlocked Package Version Creation?

Tags: salesforcedx, package, unlocked-package, fma, lmo

- My company owns a managed package with a feature licensed in the FMA.
- Inside the managed package we have a button the user presses to flip a protected metadata setting to enable the Objects/Fields associated with the feature. The button only works if the license has been granted in the FMA.
- We have unpackaged, implementation-specific metadata I'd like to migrate to unlocked packages.
- I've been able to make the unlocked package dependent on our managed package.
- We've added code to our LMO/FMA to automatically grant the license to specific scratch org configurations, which I've added as the "definitionFile" property in our package definition.

The problem: During the unlocked package version creation process, there's no way to click the button in the UI and create our protected metadata entry to enable the licensed objects, so the "Verifying Metadata" step fails when it hits a reference to them.

(I know about org-dependent unlocked packages, but would prefer not to use them, as enforcing dependency is important to our use case)

Comment: Have you checked if this could help you? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.htm

Comment: @JefersonChaves, thanks for responding. That link is a general description of dx project configuration files, but I feel like I've covered all of those bases. Let me know if there's a more specific avenue you think I should explore.

Comment: My bad, I meant to share the link related to unpackaged metadata for test: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_unpackaged_md.htm. It is in pilot but could be helpful.